# Symfony project; SonataUser, FOSUser and their registration_content.html.twig

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, user-registration, sonata-user-bundle

### **Solved** -- see bottom of entry

I'm trying to get familiar with the SonataUserBundle extending the FOSUserBundle.

The installation worked fine (as far as I can tell) and now I want to customize
the login and registration forms.
I overwrote templates in app/Resources and it worked fine. 
However, for the registration form I do not understand why it works...

Here's my problem:

The SonataUserBundle registration controller (RegistrationFOSUser1) sets up the form 
and renders it with  FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig as template:

```
$form = $this->container->get('sonata.user.registration.form');
$formHandler = $this->container->get('sonata.user.registration.form.handler');
[...]
return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

register.html.twig includes FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig:

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

register_content.html.twig contains the twig code to render the form.

However, what is actually rendered is SonataUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig

I just can't figure out where, when and how SonataUserBundle substitutes FOSUserBundle here...

Thanks for any hints!

---

Ok, I now see that the solution to my question is well documented in the symfony cookbook:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

For those as new to symfony as myself:

If you define a parent 'ParentBundle' for another bundle 'ChildBundle', then everytime a function, template etc. from ParentBundle is called, symfony will first look whether there is a file with the same name in ChildBundle.

The parent bundle is defined in the ChildBundle.php:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'ParentBundle';
}
```

This works, as long as the file of the parent bundle is called via the usual ParentBundle:path:file notation.

Comment: Please publish the result as an answer and accept it !

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I now see that the solution to my question is well documented in the symfony cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

For those as new to symfony as myself:

If you define a parent 'ParentBundle' for another bundle 'ChildBundle', then everytime a function, template etc. from ParentBundle is called, symfony will first look whether there is a file with the same name in ChildBundle.

The parent bundle is defined in the ChildBundle.php:

```
public function getParent()
{
return 'ParentBundle';
}
```

This works, as long as the file of the parent bundle is called via the usual ParentBundle:path:file notation.